# How to call the base classes overrided insertion operator in derived classes overrided insertion and add some additional information

Tags: c++, polymorphism, operator-overloading

My base class Animal has an override insertion operator with info about location X & Y of the animal. Derived class Bird need to print X & Y & Z location since it can fly. I have successfully called the base classes << operator, but unable to add info about location Z, what am I doing wrong here?

```
// BASE CLASS OPERATOR
ostream& operator<<(ostream &os, Animal &animal) {
    ostringstream oss;

    oss << "Id: " << animal.Id
        << "\nAge: " << animal.age
        << "\nStatus: " << animal.status
        << "\nLocation: " << animal.locX << ", " << animal.locY;

    os << oss.str();
    return os;
}

// DERIVED CLASS OPERATOR
ostream &operator<<(ostream &os, const Bird bird) {
    const Animal *birdPtr = &bird;
    os << "Bird" << endl; // THIS IS NOT PRINTING
    os << birdPtr;
    os << ", " << bird.locZ; //THIS IS NOT PRINTING

    return os;
}
```

Actual result:

```
Id: 1
Age: 0
Status: 1
Location: 0, 0
```

Expected result for Bird:

```
Bird
Id: 1
Age: 0
Status: 1
Location: 0, 0, 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not show how you are creating the `Bird` object and passing it to `operator<<` initially. But there are several mistakes in the code you have shown.

- in the base `operator<<`, the `Animal` parameter is being passed as a non-`const` reference.  It should be a `const` reference instead.
- in the derived `operator<<`:

  - the `Bird` parameter is being passed by value, not by a `const` reference.
  - you are trying to call your base `operator<<` using a `const Animal*` pointer, but there is no overload of `operator<<` that takes a `const Animal*` pointer as input.  There is, however, an `operator<<` in the `std:::ostream` class that takes a `const void*` as input, and all pointer types are implicitly convertible to `void*` (that operator simply prints out the memory address that the pointer is pointing to).  Since your base `operator<<` takes an `Animal&` reference, you need to pass your `Bird` object to it as an `Animal&` reference rather than as an `Animal*` pointer.

Try this instead:

```cpp
ostream& operator<<(ostream &os, const Animal &animal) {
    ostringstream oss;

    oss << "Id: " << animal.Id
        << "\nAge: " << animal.age
        << "\nStatus: " << animal.status
        << "\nLocation: " << animal.locX << ", " << animal.locY;

    os << oss.str();
    return os;
}

ostream& operator<<(ostream &os, const Bird &bird) {
    const Animal &birdRef = bird;

    os << "Bird" << endl;
    os << birdRef;
    // alternatively:
    // os << static_cast<const Animal&>(bird);
    os << ", " << bird.locZ;

    return os;
}
```

Then you can do this:

```
Bird bird;
...
std::cout << bird;
```

[Live demo](https://ideone.com/IGR085)

Comment: Thank you so much, Remy. This explanation is very helpful to me and easy to understand!